# Why does Mark call Veronica "plan B" in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, t2-trainspotting

In *T2 Trainspotting (2017)*, Simon (with his girlfriend Veronica) and Mark meet together and discuss about the past few days. Then suddenly Mark looks at his watch, which makes Simon very angry, and he wants to know why Mark is doing that. Mark replies that he has a plane to catch. And then Mark becomes even more angry, and leaves the place and takes cocaine himself. Now Mark starts talking with Veronica, and calls her **plan B**:

> Mark: So you're Plan B.
>
> Veronica: Yes.

What exactly is Mark referring to here by calling her plan B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sick Boy has tried to convince Mark to stay with him. When he sees that it is not working, he makes a show of searching a motive for leaving. That leaves Mark and Veronica alone; Sick Boy hopes that Mark will become attracted to her and so he will stay for her. That is Sick Boy's plan B.

It is so plain simple and obvious that Mark just comments it to show that he has not been fooled at all by Sick Boy performance and that Veronica can stop playing by that plan.